# Join Table To a nested array [PHP/MYSQL]

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, nested

How to select join multiple tables and get it in a nested array easily?

For Example

```
Table 1 -School: SchoolID, SchoolName,PrincipalID
Talbe 2 - Principal: PrincipalID,PrincipalName
```

I want to get a nested array in PHP like

```
"School": [
            {
                "SchoolID": "7",
                "SchoolName": "New",
                "Principal": {
                      "PrincipalID":"1",
                      "PrincipalName":"James"
                }
            }
```

The problem is, how to get the nested array use a automatic way instead of specifying each field and add it into a array manually? without even kowning the actual field names, just nesting multiple tables into a nested array.

Answer (score 0):

the result of the query can be a single dimension array only. so in other words, you can't create a multidimensional result. You need to do that in the application level, (*use your own logic*) but there's a function that can help you sometime. It's called **[`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)**. What it does it is it concatenates its row values into single row and separated by a comma.

- [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)
- [GROP_CONCAT example](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/)

Comment: I have seen someone did that but don't know how. This Group_Concat can't help