# Multi-Level MYSQL Query In One Select Statement

Tags: mysql, concatenation, multi-level

Pretty straightforward SQL question here - I have three levels of data spread out over three tables. 
**Table 1- Listings**, 
**Table 2 - Interests**,
**Table 3 - Messages**

Table 1 -> Table 2, and Table 2 -> Table 3 have a One-To-Many Relationship

*There will always be listings, but there may or may not be interests for each listing, and there may or may not be messages for each interest.*

What I want to do is select all the information in ***1 Select Statement*** in order to avoid multiple database calls.

I know with *two levels of information* you can use GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP BY to grab all the second level information into a concatenated string column. I just don't know what to do with three levels if I want to use only one select.
I also know how this can be done with two separate calls and a PHP/python script in between, but I want to avoid that for performance.

Ideally I would get back an array that looks like this:

```
array(
     '1'=>array(listingId'=>1, 
                interests=>
                           array(
                                 array(
                                       'interestId'=>2
                                       'messages'=>array(
                                                         'messageId'=>5,
                                                         'message'=>'hi'
                                                         ),
                                                   ...
                                       ),
                                ...
                                ),
                          ...
                ),
     ...
     )
```

Another ideal situation would be to get:

```
 array(
     '1'=>array(listingId'=>1, 
                interests=>
                           array(
                                 array('interestId'=>2,
                                       'messages'=>INSERT CONCATENATED STRING HERE
                                      ),
                                 ...
                                ),
                           ...
                ),
     ...
     )
```

With this situation I could just use a PHP/Python/Ruby script to parse the concatenated string of message.

**The dots represent more arrays with similar data.**

The most significant problem with trying to use concatenation is that you can only pull back one column using a subselect.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I'm testing some things on my own database. I'll be back soon

Comment: Sounds great. I find it pretty crazy that there doesn't seem to be an easy solution to this because it seems like a pretty common database call!

Comment: check my updated answer. You should change some table names and fields, as they didn't match exactly

Comment: Just checked it out - the problem with this solution is that the interests information is lost in between. After studying this issue over and over, I really don't see any elegant solution to this, which is so surprising to me given how it seems to be a fairly standard procedure. I think I am going to go with pulling back all the listing information, and then all the interests that are concatenated, and then the messages information for all the interests, also concatenated. The intent is to the then parse the messages and assign them to each interest. =/

Comment: Indeed, information is lost in between. I'm sorry I couldn't give you a better solution !

Comment: Yeah, it's okay! I guess there just isn't any elegant solution to this :(. Thank you for your time, effort and help though, I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just join all the tables?

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE table3.ref=table2.id AND table2.ref=table1.id
```

I don't know which foreign index you use, so I just used `ref` and `id`.

[EDIT]
Another solution, in 1 call, is using different `GROUP_CONCAT` instructions, with different separators, like this:

```
SELECT naam,GROUP_CONCAT(t4.messages SEPARATOR '#') FROM test_listing t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.id,t2.ref,GROUP_CONCAT(message SEPARATOR '=') as messages FROM test_message t3 RIGHT JOIN test_interest t2 ON t2.id=t3.ref GROUP BY t2.id) t4 ON t1.id=t4.ref GROUP BY t1.id
```

This will return as many records as you have listings, and then combines all messages with separator '=', after which it will combine all these with '#'

I don't see a more elegant solution to this problem ! Also, neither is there a more elegant solution on the topic [Join Table To a nested array [PHP/MYSQL]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437378/join-table-to-a-nested-array-php-mysql).

Comment: Joining the tables has a few problems I want to avoid - the most primary one being that the information being returned is duplicated in a one to many format. That requires unnecessary processing in a PHP script, which can be avoided when one uses a GROUP BY function to group related information together. ALSO, if that were the case I would most likely use a LEFT JOIN since there will always be listings, but there may not be any interests for each listing and there may not be any messages for each interest.

Comment: I see what you want to achieve, but I don't think that it is possible since Mysql returns its results in rows and not objects. `GROUP_CONCAT` is just combining some data into one cell.

Comment: So do you think the way I am doing it now is the best way to do it? Pulling back all the listings, and then for each listing going back to the server to get related Interests and Messages? Since I may have 30 listings, that would mean 30 different calls to the database to get interests and messages for each listing. I just really think there has to be a better way... And yes, but GROUP_CONCAT lets me concatenate DISTINCT rows back into a string which is why it's very useful - I can iterate over the row using a script to parse the data. That's faster than making multiple database calls.

Comment: I think you have to join the tables, so you only need one call to the database. You could group them with group_concat, using different separators for the first and second join. Afterwards in PHP, you could use `explode` to split every entry into the correct arrays. In this case, the database resultset contains as many rows as there are listings.

Comment: How would I pull back the second join information as a result of the first join information? Column wise, I could pull back listingId, listing_name, and then interests (as a concatenated string of distinct results). How would I then pull back the third level information of messages that is related to the interests? Pulling it back as a concatenated string would require exploding the concatenated messages string and the added step of figuring out which message belongs to which interest by using foreach. That's a better way of doing it than making 30 calls, but is that the best way to do it?